# Finding out type within dir()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say we doing the following:

```
for i in dir(foo):

    print type(i)
```

This setup will give back a list of strings, but I'm more interested in finding out the type of the items inside of foo. What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dir()` only gives you the names of the attributes; use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to retrieve the actual attribute:

```
for i in dir(foo):
    attr = getattr(foo, i)
    print type(attr)
```

You might also be interested in the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html); the [`inspect.getmembers()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) lists names plus attributes for you:

```
from inspect import getmembers

for name, attr in getmembers(foo):
    print '{}: {}'.format(name, type(attr))
```

In addition, `getmembers()` lets you filter on attribute type as well:

```
from inspect import getmembers, ismethod

for name, attr in getmembers(foo, ismethod):
    print '{}: {}'.format(name, type(attr))
```

would only show you bound methods on `foo`.

Comment: Based on my time feed, SO thought we were 11 seconds apart, but I think it was closer than that.  Anyway, you've FGITW me again (When will I learn dvorak?)  :-P.  +1

Comment: @mgilson: looking at the timestamps, there are 5 seconds between the posts. :-)

Comment: I thought it was less than 11 seconds!  :).